# Why is git soft delete deleting branches that have not been merged?

Tags: git

Here are my theoretical git branches:

```
master
feature/something
feature/something-else
```

If the branch I am currently on is `master` and `feature/something` has not been merged into `master` then `git br -d feature/something` should not successfully delete `feature/something`. `feature/something` has not been merged into `master` and the `-d` flag should be a guard against `feature/something` getting deleted. However lately I've noticed that this soft delete does not guard me from deleting this unmerged branch -- `feature/something`. In fact `git br -d feature/something` will  indeed delete `feature/something`, and I'll receive the following warning from git:

```
warning: deleting branch 'feature/something' that has been merged to
         'refs/remotes/origin/feature/something', but not yet merged to HEAD.
```

Why did `git` delete a branch my local branch `feature/something` when `feature/something` was not merged into `master` -- which was my current branch?

Answer (score 3):

The full documentation for [`git branch -d`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#git-branch--d) reads:

```
-d::
--delete::
    Delete a branch. The branch must be fully merged in its
    upstream branch, or in `HEAD` if no upstream was set with
    `--track` or `--set-upstream-to`.
```

And your warning messages says, that `feature/something` **had** an upstream branch configured (`origin/feature/something`) and hence the `HEAD` part (`master` in your case) did not apply.

This behaviour has been documented since 2010-04-15 (in commit fff0d0abdd) - so it is not really new.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I got to say, sometimes I get lost in the language of git. I'm going to post an answer because I think it would be good to share my findings.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the following error message:

> warning: deleting branch 'feature/something' that has been merged to
>            'refs/remotes/origin/feature/something', but not yet merged to HEAD.

because the branch that I am 'soft' deleting `git br -d feature/something` used to have a remote branch `origin/feature/something`. In the above [question / use case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52998278/2524631) `feature/something` had been merged into remote master -- `origin/master` -- but I had not updated my local copy of `master`. Therefore, when I tried to delete softly `git br -d feature/something` with my current branch as `master` indeed I succeeded because the remote `origin/master` copy includes the history of `origin/feature/something`.

In other words, the behavior is still an arguably safe operation -- a soft deletion. The branch locally gets deleted without potentially losing any work but lets me know that locally `master` does not include the branch `feature/something`, hence, the message just being a warning.